# In python Turtle, set correct turtle position

Tags: python, position, turtle-graphics

I will try to explain what I mean. I'm working on a Pong game version. I've placed to paddles next to the borders. One for player1 and one for player2. Inside the game window, created using Screen class, I set width and height using , let's say, screen.setup(width=800, height=600). Even if I use "same" x coordinates the two paddles seem to place themself in a slightly different position: player1 where I want, player2 too close to the right border.
Screenshot attached.
As you can see from the code below I've created a Player Class and the X position inside two functions is the "same", one -380 while the opposite is 380 but the paddles end up having different position.

```
def create_player1_paddle(self):
    self.color("white")
    self.penup()
    self.shape("square")
    self.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
    self.goto(-380, 0)

def create_player2_paddle(self):
    self.color("white")
    self.penup()
    self.shape("square")
    self.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
    self.goto(380, 0)
```

Do you know why is that?
Sorry for my English, hope you get what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the coordinates of the shape refer to its center and not, for example, top left corner?

Comment: My answer to [Turtle Graphics Unequal Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67454225/5771269) might help you with this, also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62072855/5771269)